# cannot locate .android file on my mac to obain a maps key?

Tags: android

I am making an android application in which i need to include Google maps.
I have read and found out that i need to procure a maps keep before i can do this.

i need to find the **debug.keystore** file on my mac so that i can obtain the maps key for my application.

For this i have checked the preferences-> android-> build option from where i am finding the path for the debug.keystore file.

But when i go to this actually, i cannot find a .android folder.

i have even searched in my spotlight for this folder but i could not get any results.

where do i find the folder?

thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you 'unhide' the folder?

Answer (score 2):

turns out the .android folder was in my user folder, but was hidden. i had to unhide it and then i found the keystore file

I am answering my own question as several people have voted up my question, so even they would find my solution useful. After all it is a team effort. whoever finds the answer first should share with the team.

thank you.